# Volatile variable assignment in a synchronized block results in null

Tags: java, lambda, concurrency, volatile

here's a class:

```
public class Refreshable<T> {
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    private final Supplier<Object>[] dynamicSettings;
    private final Supplier<T> constructor;

    private volatile Object[] instanceKey;
    private volatile T instance;

    @SafeVarargs
    public Refreshable(Supplier<T> constructor, Supplier<Object>... dynamicSettings) {
        this.constructor = constructor;
        this.dynamicSettings = dynamicSettings;
    }

    public T getInstance() {
        Object[] currentKey = getCurrentKey();
        if (!Arrays.equals(currentKey, instanceKey)) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (!Arrays.equals(currentKey, instanceKey)) {
                    instanceKey = currentKey;
                    instance = constructor.get();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private Object[] getCurrentKey() {
        return Arrays.stream(dynamicSettings)
                .map(Supplier::get)
                .toArray();
    }
}
```

The idea is in the name: return new instance when values of the parameters relevant for its creation have changed. `constructor` is always a lambda wrapping a constructor - it can't return null. It can throw an exception, though
Used in our project like this:

```
new Refreshable<Service>(
    () -> new Service(settings.getParam1(), settings.getParam2()),
    settings::getParam1,
    settings::getParam1);
```

where parameter values returned by `settings` can change over time.

Long story short, under some load testing `getInstance()` returned null to several threads on first invocation (10 or more of them in the same second), at a line like this: `serviceRefreshable.getInstance().someMethod()`. So it's either the refreshable that was null, or the result of getInstance() and the fact that the error didn't repeat later in the run suggests the latter because refreshable is only assigned once (it's a singleton bean).

I understand that the `constructor` can throw an exception and prevent `instance` from being assigned, but it's not in the log (and NPE is).

`Arrays.equals()` here can't return true unexpectedly, because `instanceKey` is null initially and `getCurrentKey()` can't return null.  All `dynamicSettings` suppliers are lambdas wrapping this invocation:

```
private <T> T getValue(String key, Class<T> type) {
    Object value = properties.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("No such setting: " + key);
    }
    if (!type.isInstance(value)) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("Wrong setting type" + key);
    }
    return (T) value;
}
```

How is this possible?

I also understand one can safeguard against this by wrapping instance and instanceKey in one object and reducing 2 assignments to one to make them atomic, as well as checking for `instance == null` along with comparing arrays. 
What I don't understand is where the hell did the exception that caused `constructor` to fail go :)

I even edited the production code to throw a RuntimeException in a `constructor` lambda supplied to one of these `Refreshables` and sure enough, I saw that exception in the log instead of a NPE. Wasn't under any kind of concurrent load, though

Comment: Well there _is_ a race condition where `instanceKey` has been assigned inside the synchronized block but `instance` has not and may be null.  But this would only happen off the start.

Comment: Can you show us the code that handles the getInstance() results and any exceptions? Have you tried to add an if instance == null to see if you are actually getting null as opposed to not handling an exception right?

Comment: Elaborated a bit more in the post. 
I mentioned the possibility of an exception happening between the two assignments, but there's no code to hide that exception - checked and checked again :) I would have seen it in the log

Comment: Hi, I know your making a question but I wan't to ask you about the use of this refreshable table: the contextual use case, because I had never seen something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Long story short, under some load testing getInstance() returned null to several threads on first invocation

As I mentioned in my comment, there is a race condition where `instanceKey` has been assigned *inside* the synchronized block but `instance` has not yet been assigned and may be null.  So after the one thread assigns the key, other threads will test the key, find it not null and equals and continue to return a null `instance`.

I think the creation of a class which holds both values is in order.  I initially implemented this inside of an `AtomicReference` but I think just using `volatile` will get the job done.  Something like:

```
private volatile InstanceInfo<T> instanceInfo;
...
public T getInstance() {
    // we store this in a non-volatile to only touch the volatile field once and to
    // ensure we have a consistent view of the instanceInfo value
    InstanceInfo<T> localInstanceInfo = instanceInfo;
    if (localInstanceInfo == null || !Arrays.equals(currentKey, localInstanceInfo.key)) {
       localInstanceInfo = new InstanceInfo<>(currentKey, constructor.get());
       instanceInfo = localInstanceInfo;
    }
    return localInstanceInfo.instance;
}
...
private static class InstanceInfo<T> {
   final Object[] key;
   final T instance; 
   public InstanceInfo(Object[] key, T instance) {
       this.key = key;
       this.instance = instance;
   }
}
```

Comment: yep, that's what has been done, albeit without realization that a race condition is going on

Comment: Note that using the local variable as `InstanceInfo<T> localInstanceInfo = instanceInfo;` is crucial, not only to “touch the volatile field once”, but to ensure that the subsequent operation consistently uses the same state, as reading the variable multiple times would open again the possibility of race conditions. Further, it’s important to understand that this might do more work than necessary when multiple thread enter the method in an outdated state, as each of them might calculate a new value for the same key.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have sufficient synchronization to guarantee that a thread that sees an updated value of `instanceKey` also sees the corresponding value of `instance`. So, a calling thread can bypass the `synchronized` block, and return `instance` before it is assigned the first time.

```
Thread 1                          Thread 2
-------------------------         ----------------------------
instanceKey = currentKey;
                                  if (!Arrays.equals(currentKey, instanceKey)) {} // false
                                  return instance;
instance = constructor.get();
```

You are assuming that the assignment of `instanceKey` and `instance` to appear to be atomic to all other threads. But that won't happen unless all other threads read those variables while synchronized on the same lock.

Comment: Thank you
So packaging the two values in a single object such that the assignment is atomic appears to be the way to go

Comment: @bruto I have not dived into your example, but generally you could piggy back one variable by making the other volatile, but that will ensure only visibility and no re-orderings, not atomicity; might not be what you need exactly

Comment: now that I know the answer, the question can be made much shorter :)